# Conceptual explanation of the Single particle partition function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, partition-function

The Single particle partition function is defined mathematically as
$$\text{Z=$\sum $}g_ie^{\left(\frac{-E_i}{K_BT}\right)}$$

But what is the physical interpretation of the partition function and it's significance to Thermodynamics? I'm seeking a simple yet understandable intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what is the physical interpretation of the partition function and
>   it's significance to Thermodynamics? I'm seeking a simple yet
>   understandable intuition.

The partition function has one simple physical interpretation in terms of Thermodynamic functions: Its natural log is proportional to the Free Energy (the proportionality constant is the negative inverse temperature).

The Free Energy, which is well-known from Thermodynamics, is given by
$$
F=E-TS\;,
$$ 
where E is the Thermodynamics Energy, T is the temperature, and S is the Entropy.

From a Statistical Mechanics perspective, remember that the probability to be in a state $n$ is given by
$$
p_n\equiv \frac{e^{-E_n/T}}{Z}\;,
$$
where $Z$ is your partition function, T is the temperature, and $E_n$ is the energy of state $n$.

The statistical definition of Entropy is
$$
S=-\sum_n p_n \log(p_n)
$$
$$
=-\sum_n p_n (-E_n/T-\log(Z))
$$
$$
=E/T+\log(Z)
$$

I.e.,
$$
S-E/T=\log(Z)=-F/T
$$

Answer (score 1):

Partition functions are a measure of the allowed volume in (microscopic-)configuration space for the system, and as such they are the normalizing function for probabilities expressed as volumes in configuration space (and assuming the applicability of the ergodic hypothesis).

---

I know that this is very abstract, but it is also very general.

Comment: What exactly is 'configuration space' and could you expound in greater depth the ideal of an allowed volume in such configuration space?

Comment: Configuration space is an abstract space the components of which are the positions and momenta of every independent mass in the system. You'll note that this can be a very high dimensional space. But if you don't have this concept then you probably need a different formulation of the meaning of the partition function. Alas, I'm still working on my own conceptual foundation for statistical physics, so I don't have the right one to offer.